# Qatar Airways Eco Power Outlet A350

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, power, qatar-airways, airbus

I recently booked an itinerary, containing a leg on Qatar's A350. I found an image on seatguru showing power outlets. 
Did somebody fly the A350 in eco and can tell me if I can use a standard German laptop charger (230V, 50Hz) or do I need an adapter?

[image: taken form seatguru]

Comment: Are you sure your laptop charger is 230/50 only? Most are happy with 110-240

Comment: yes, sure, 100-240 will work. I'm just not sure if it will work physically for the german plugs: http://www.tuxgraphics.org/electronics/powersockets/power_plug_frde.jpg

Comment: I can't find a reference, but I'm pretty confident it will. That looks like a standard generic international socket, designed to take European, UK, US, and probably Aus/NZ plugs. You see them a lot these days in planes, international hotels, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the logo on the socket, this is an "EmPower" socket - which isn't surprising as they are the most common type of these sockets on airplanes.

You can find a datasheet for these types of sockets [here](http://www.astronics.com/PartFiles/MDS0054%201295-X-X%20USB%20OU%20110217.pdf), that claims they are "Compatible with plugs from over 170 countries", and then specifically shows compatibility with multiple forms of 2-plug European power sockets (earthed and unearthed)

So yes, this socket will accept your German power plug, along with plug from most other countries, without an adapter.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the German type plug will fit in there, if you look closely you will notice a curved notch in the outlet made for round pins. Check the end of the arrow:

[image]

Actually, plugs with round pins are the standard in Qatar the country, along with the UK type.